# JSX inline conditionals and the falsey value "0" are acting strange

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit surprised over the behaviour of the component below.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {true && <p>with "true"</p>}
        {false && <p>with "false"</p>}
        {1 && <p>with 1</p>}
        {0 && <p>with 0</p>}
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The way the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator) says this is supposed to work is

> It works because in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

Now I would expect the above component to render

```
<p>with "true"</p>
```

since only the first condition is `true`, and I would also accept seeing

```
<p>with "true"</p>
<p>with 1</p>
```

since both `true` and `1` are truthy values.

What it does render, however, is

```
<p>with "true"</p>
<p>with 1</p>
0
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozVEBY)

Why is this? What is it that JSX considers to be so special about `0`? The bevaviour above seem to contradict both the aforementioned statements from the docs about how the `&&` operator are supposed to work.

Comment: Where is the code to render a `<p>` tag with just a `0` inside?

Comment: @TomFenech Oops, sorry. The `0` is not in a `<p>` tag. It's just a `0`. Well, react adds a `<span>` around it but that's not the point. Why did it render the first half of the `&&` statement?

Comment: `(0 && whatever)` evaluates to `0` and returns it, thus printing the `0`.

Comment: @pawel Ah, thanks. I had a hard time knowing what to google for here.

Comment: @ivarni no problem, I've had a hard time finding my own answer to a similar question, just knew I've explained this before. Didn't want to copy/paste, so marked as a duplicate.